# Как удалить сохраняемые фильтры google таблицы. Google Sheet API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

В гугл таблицах, есть сохраняемые фильтры. Необходимо удалить все фильтры, создаваемые по умолчанию.
[image: со]

Answer (score 1):

**Для удаления на конкретном листе**, в Google Spreadsheet есть кнопка "Удалить все фильтры":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если требуется **массовое удаление со всех листов**, то:

Немного модифицировал и упростил код представленный выше. Этот код удаляет все сохраненные фильтры во всём документе Spreadsheet (не на конкретном листе). Как и в предыдущем посте **требуется подключить сервис Google Sheets API**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function delete_all_filterView_ss() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const ss_id = ss.getId();

  const arr_filterViewId = [];

  const ss_obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss_id);

  for (const i of ss_obj.sheets) {
    if (i.filterViews != null) {
      for (const j of i.filterViews) {
        arr_filterViewId.push(j.filterViewId)
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log(arr_filterViewId);

  for (const value_filterId of arr_filterViewId) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      "requests": [
        {
          "deleteFilterView": {
            "filterId": value_filterId
          }
        }
      ]
    }, ss_id);
  }

}
```

'#delete all filter views at once in Google Sheets
'#Как удалить все фильтры в таблице Google?
'#Google Apps Script to delete all the filter views in a spreadshet
'#Массовое удаление представлений фильтров в google
'#Mass Delete Filter Views in Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение  и хочу поделиться с вами им.
Если кому-то надо удалить вообще все фильтры, тот вот [тут](https://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2019/06/google-apps-script-to-delete-all-filter-views.html?showComment=1599553218521#c3046117636817927964) есть решение проблемы.

Чтобы удалить фильтры, надо использовать REST API метод [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate?hl=ru)
Не забудьте включить Google Sheets Api. Во вкладке Ресурсы-> Дополнительные Функции Google.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ниже мой код, который удаляет все фильтры, содержащие подстроку "Фильтр". Таким образом, удалит все созданные по умолчанию фильтры.

```
 function delete_filters() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  
  var id_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var substr = "Фильтр";
  var arr_filterViewId = [];
  

  
 var json_obj  = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id, {
    fields: 'sheets/filterViews',
  });
  
 for(var i = 0; i < json_obj.sheets.length; i++)
     {
       if(json_obj.sheets[i].filterViews != null)
       {
       for(var i2 = 0; i2 < json_obj.sheets[i].filterViews.length; i2++)
       {
         var current_filterView = json_obj.sheets[i].filterViews[i2];
         var sheetId = current_filterView.range.sheetId;
         if(sheetId === id_sheet)
         {
           var  str_title = current_filterView.title; 
           if(str_title.includes(substr))
           {
             arr_filterViewId.push(JSON.stringify(current_filterView.filterViewId));
           }
         }
         
       } // end of 2 for
       }
     }
  
  Logger.log(arr_filterViewId);
  
  for(var x =0 ; x < arr_filterViewId.length; x++)
  {
    var value_filterId = parseInt(arr_filterViewId[x],10);
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      "requests": [
        {
          "deleteFilterView": {
            "filterId": value_filterId
          }
        }
      ]
    },id);
  }
  
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(json_obj.sheets[3].filterViews[0].range.sheetId));
}
```